# Convert PHP pregmatch pattern to C# pattern

Tags: c#, php, regex

I have a PHP preg_match pattern to filter Call of Duty (Quake Engine) Colour in names,

This is the pattern in PHP which works

```
 preg_replace('~(\^[0-9])~', '', $CleanNames);
```

I need to convert it to C#. Something like `Something.Replace(~(\^[0-9])~, string)` pattern

And since patterns / regex are really confusing and makes little sense to me.
Can someone help please. Or is there a Place that I can convert it ?

Any help will be much appreciated !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`~` are warping the regex in your `PHP`. So remove those from there in `c#`

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
string input = Regex.Replace(input, @"(\^[0-9])", "");
```

You'll find plenty of [sites like this](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl) to get the explanation of your regex.

Comment: Thank you so Much for the fast response and Help. I'm new to C# and didn't know C# has Regex in it to use. This makes life a lot easier. Its Working. The site provided will come in handy. Again thanks